# I can't implement interface of same package in java

Tags: java

I have a package called rmi_prg. I have one public interface in that named Adder. The code of the file Adder.java is following :

```
package rmi_prg;
import java.rmi.*;
public interface Adder extends Remote
{
public int add(int x,int y)throws RemoteException;
}
```

I have another file in that same folder rmi_prg named remoteadder.java . And the code of that file is following :

```
package rmi_prg;
import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.server.*;

public class remoteadder extends UnicastRemoteObject implements Adder
{
remoteadder() throws RemoteException
{
super();
}

public int add(int x,int y)
{
    return x+y;
}

}
```

When I compile Adder.java, it gets compiled. But when I am trying to compile remoteadder.java file, I am getting the following error :

> remoteadder.java:4: error: cannot find symbol public class remoteadder
>   implements Adder{
>                                       ^   symbol: class Adder 1 error

I am compiling both of the files from directory rmi_prg. Can anyone please help me to solve this ?

Thank you :)

Comment: Check to make sure the files are in the proper directories in your project architecture

Comment: both of the files are in directory called rmi_prg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are running `javac` from `rmi_prg` directory and thus your classpath is broken.

Go to the parent directory of rmi_prg and run:

```
javac rmi_prg\Adder.java
```

and then

```
javac rmi_prg\remoteadder.java
```

Off-topic: consider capitalizing your class name to follow the Java naming convention.

Comment: Yeah. It worked. Thanks a lot. But I didn't get the logic for that. :(  and I will definitely follow naming conventions :)

Comment: I recommend using an IDE like Eclipse so you don't have to manually compile every class.